# Skip payment method step if only one payment method is active

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, quote, currency

I am looking for a way to hide/skip the payment method step if there is only one payment method active.

I haven't started work on the task because I am not entirely sure if it is achievable due to how the checkout process uses Javascript etc I am not sure how I could do a comparison check in order to skip the step.

For example,

Once the billing and shipping information has been set I'd like to show the `Place order button` rather than goto the payment method step since there will only be one method available.

At the moment I am thinking to use an Observer of some sort but I doubt this will work due the Javascript that loads each step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Observer to see the currency and enable Check/Money order for this type of payment (with another name of course) and once the order is placed do your Magic.

I made something similar [here](https://github.com/miguelbalparda/MB_AdminMoney) for another objective but you can reuse most of the code.

Comment: thanks for your comment and code reference I'm sure it will come in useful. I'm still scratching my head about how I would skip the `payment method` step altogether and go straight to the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

You will find [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/reduced-checkout-free.html) free extension very helpful for what you want to achieve.

PS.  I am no way related to extension.